# want to display contacts table when i click on one account

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am having account table with name,email,.. fields. If i click on one account my requirement is to display its contacts in a table format.

My code is:

```
<apex:page controller="custable" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="AccountTable">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Acclst}" var="A">
            <apex:column headerValue="EDIT">
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!A.id}/e" id="edit">Edit</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="DELETE">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteAccount}" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;">Del
            <apex:param value="{!A.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!recid}"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="NAME OF THE ACCOUNT" > 
            <apex:commandLink value="{!A.Name}" action="/{!A.id}"/>
            </apex:column>  
            <apex:column value="{!A.Id}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller is:

```
public with sharing class custable {

     public string recid{get;set;}
       public string row{ get; set;}
       public list<Account> Acclst{get;set;}
       Public Account A;



       public custable(){

       Acclst = [select Id,Name from Account ];

}
       public pagereference deleteAccount()
       {
       account ac=[select id,name from account where id=:recid];
       delete ac;


       pagereference ref =new pagereference('/apex/custable');
       ref.setredirect(true);
       return ref;

}
}
```

previously i redirected to record detail page. But now requirement is to display contacts table when i click on a account record.

Comment: <apex:commandLink value="{!A.Name}" action="/003?rlid=RelatedContactList&id={!A.Id}"/>

Answer (score 3):

You'll need the following for this:

1. A list of contacts property in the controller
2. A table that iterates a list of contacts from the controller
3. An action method that retrieves the list of contacts for the
   specified account
4. A commandlink that executes the action method, passing the account id into the controller, and then rerenders the table of contacts

Something like the following:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class custable {

     public string recid{get;set;}

   public string row{ get; set;}
   public list<Account> Acclst{get;set;}
   Public Account A;

   public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}

   public custable(){

   Acclst = [select Id,Name from Account ];
   contacts=null;
   }

   public pagereference deleteAccount()
   {
   account ac=[select id,name from account where id=:recid];
   delete ac;


   pagereference ref =new pagereference('/apex/custable');
   ref.setredirect(true);
   return ref;

  }

  public void setupContacts()
  {
     contacts=[select id, FirstName, LastName from Contact where AccountId=:recId];
      }
   }
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="custable" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="AccountTable">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Acclst}" var="A">
            <apex:column headerValue="EDIT">
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!A.id}/e" id="edit">Edit</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="DELETE">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteAccount}" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;">Del
            <apex:param value="{!A.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!recid}"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="NAME OF THE ACCOUNT" > 
            <apex:commandLink value="{!A.Name}" action="{!setupContacts}" rerender="conttable">
              <apex:param value="{!A.Id}" name="idForConts" assignTo="{!recid}"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>  
            <apex:column value="{!A.Id}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="contact" id="conttable">
        <apex:column value="{!contact.id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: pagereference ref =new pagereference('/apex/custable');
The page reference redirect to record detail page but contact records are not displaying in table for contacts.

Comment: Sorry - mistake in my code - return type should be void.  The page shouldn't change, because of the rerender attribute.  Instead it will just update the table - I've updated the action method signature.

Comment: I've tweaked the contact bit slightly, as it looked awful - its now a pageblocktable.  I've verified this exact page and controller is working in my dev org.  Do you have any contacts defined for the account you are selecting?

Answer (score 0):

@Bob,I'm trying to display contacts under the same account(on click of + symbol for expand) in the form of table not at the bottom of the account table.But particular account columns also coming side by side of contact table.